# How to shorten space between triangle and text in spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, spinner

[Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YItfL.png)

Q1. How can I shorten space between triangle and text in Spinner?

Q2. How to extend the dropdown menu like photo(dotted line)?

Q3. How can I change the dropdown menus theme to light?

My source codes

▼Layout

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0" />
```

▼Java File

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            R.layout.listitem, new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("ENGLISH");
        add("RUSSIAN");
    }});
```

▼listitem

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```